# Words and phrases with non-evident prejudice

Tags: etimología, vocabulario, lenguaje-peyorativo

Hace poco aprendí que el origen de la palabra *[algarabía](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=algarab%C3%ADa)* es la pronunciación de *árabe* en la lengua árabe. Otro ejemplo notable es la palabra *[morisqueta](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?LEMA=morisqueta)*.

¿Existen otras palabras o frases de común uso actualmente cuyo origen prejuiciado no es evidente?

---

Not long ago I learned that the origin of the word [algarabía](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=algarab%C3%ADa) is the pronunciaction of *Arabic* in the Arabic language. Another example is the word [morisqueta](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?LEMA=morisqueta).

Are there other words or phrases currently in common use whose prejudiced origin is not evident?

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con "prejuicioso"? No he encontrado esa palabra y también aquí me dice que no es correcta. Además, ¿quieres saber si hay otras palabras con origen árabe?

Comment: Una palabra basada en un prejuicio. _Algarabía_ y _morisqueta_ parecen provenir de una percepción negativa del lenguaje (_algarabía_) y las costumbres religiosas (_morisqueta_) de los hispano-árabes.

Comment: @Alenanno: In the translation I added which isn't approved yet I translated it literally as "prejudiced". I think that's correct?

Comment: Tenemos ejemplos en ingles, tambien -- "gypped" refiere a un a persona que ha sufrido una trampa, y refiere a los gitanos y la percepcion (veradera o falsa) que tuvieron los europeos del oeste. Tambien hay la frase, "Irish twins," que refiere a dos ninos que fueron nacido dentro de un ano. Entonces, sus edades seran la misma por un tiempo. Este es un metodo grosero de referir a la percepcion que tuvieron las inglesas a los irlandeses y su "inhabilidad" de mostar comedido con respecto a las relaciones sexuales.

Comment: @hippietrail I was "protesting" because I don't think "prejuicioso" exists in Spanish (although I'm obviously not 100% sure)... If you know it exists in English for sure, then it's perfect! :)

Comment: No I'm not 100% sure, I translated that particular word with Google Translate and it seemed to fit perfectly so I accepted it. It's not in the DRAE though. \-:

Comment: I changed _prejuicioso_ to _prejuiciado_ since the latter is in the [DRAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=prejuiciado).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tanto de palabras como de expresiones.

[Mostrar la hilacha](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostrar_la_hilacha) es el primero que me viene a la mente.

Comment: Por si el enlace muere: la frase proviene de la costumbre de los cripto-judíos de esconder la vestimenta que podía delatarlos, especialmente los [tzitzit](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzitzit) por que éstos fácilmente quedaban al descubierto.

Answer (score 0):

Averiguando el origen de [mostrar la hilacha](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/265/palabras-o-frases-con-etimologia-prejuiciada/311#311) encontré el de [¡Martes, no te cases ni te embarques!](http://archivo.lavoz.com.ar/2005/0830/opinion/nota353334_1.htm) El tercer día (el martes) es el único en la Creación del Génesis que menciona más de una vez el versículo *Y vio Dios que era bueno*. Por lo tanto, los judíos preferían contraer matrimonio o abordar un barco este día de la semana por que lo consideraban doblemente bendito. Por lo tanto, un casarse o embarcarse en un martes era una forma de *mostrar la hilacha*.